# I'm trying to export db values to a global scope so I can use in other modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, discord.js

I run a SELECT query on a db in another module, and I wanted to export the values globally so I can use in other modules.

This is what I have at the moment:

**./app.js**

```
var modules = require('./modules')
var m_db = modules.m_db
ayanami.on('ready', () => {
  // Already tested and ConnectDB/CreateDB are working
  const cnDB = m_db.ConnectDB.ConnectDB(config, config.dbFullPath);
  const crDB = m_db.CreateDB.CreateDB(m_db);
  // Created the vars because node said it wasn't declared
  var botName, botLocale, botPrefix, botOkColor, botErrorColor, botLogColor, botDonoColor, botDateFormat;
  // Called the module (I'll post it's code below)
  const confDB = m_db.BotConfig.BotConfig(m_db);
  // And tried to log a field from the db
  console.log(botDateFormat);
  // [...]
```

**./modules/index.js**

```
var m_db = require('./db/index')
module.exports = { m_db }
```

**./modules/db/index.js**

```
const ConnectDB = require('./connect');
const CreateDB = require('./create');
const BotConfig = require('./config');
module.exports = { ConnectDB, CreateDB, BotConfig }
```

**./modules/db/config.js**

```
const BotConfig = (m_db) => {
  db.each('SELECT * FROM bot_config', function(err, row){
    var botLocale = row.locale
    // [...]
    var botDateFormat = row.dateformat
    return botLocale, botDateFormat;
  })
}
module.exports = { BotConfig }
```

botDateFormat returns 'undefined', any idea why?

Comment: Where is the variable undefined?

Comment: when I try to log it in **app.js**; if I try to log it in **config.js** it returns "DD-MM-YYYY" as it should

Comment: I'll research about async then, thank you very much!